# Change class of all element within parent element jquery

Tags: jquery, css

When clicking on one element within a parent div, id like to change that elements class, whilst also changing all other elements within the same parent. So far my code looks like this

```
$(".vehicle_block").unbind().click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var booking_id = $("#booking_id").val();
    var vehicle_no = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var vehicle_id = $(this).attr('name');


    $(this).attr('class','vehicle_block selected');

});
```

So when a .vehicle_block element is clicked add the selected class. If the user was to then click a different .vehicle_block within the same parent I'd like to remove the previous select class and add it to the new element clicked.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ is one way

```
$(".vehicle_block").unbind().click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var booking_id = $("#booking_id").val();
    var vehicle_no = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var vehicle_id = $(this).attr('name');


    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```